# FullSimplify does not work well (require answer in terms of a particular variable)

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

(new to Mathematica)

I am trying to simplify the Schwarzian derivative of f w.r.t. u.(In[10]). Here f is prime of Weierstrass function (In[8]) which has some constraints (In[9])

```
In[8]:= f[u_] := D[g[u], u]

In[9]:= f[u]^2 == 4 g[u]^3 - a*g[u] - b

Out[9]= Derivative[1][g][u]^2 == -b - a g[u] + 4 g[u]^3

In[10]:= FullSimplify[f'''[u]/f'[u] - 1.5 f''[u]^2/f'[u]^2]
```

gives the output (for some reason Out[10] is of this form on copying)

```
(
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "4", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[u] (g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u] - 1.5 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(g\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[u]^2)/(g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u]^2
```

The output is in terms of primes of g[u] and the expression is not simplified. Any help is appriciated. I would prefer if the answer was a function of g[u].

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but the following code

```
ruleg = Derivative[1][g][u] :> f[u];
f[u_] := Sqrt[4 g[u]^3 - a g[u] - b];
dg[ex_] := D[ex, u] /. ruleg // Simplify;
f0 = f[u]; f1 = dg[f0]; f2 = dg[f1]; f3 = dg[f2];
S = f3/f1 - 3/2 f2^2/f1^2 // Factor;
S /. g[u] -> g // InputForm
```

returns the result

```
(12*(2*a*b + 3*a^2*g + 48*b*g^2 + 16*a*g^3 - 48*g^5))/(a - 12*g^2)^2
```

which agrees with the result that I found using PARI/GP. Notice the `InputForm` which allows me to simply copy/paste the result. Without it you get convoluted mess that you found with `Out[10]`. Notice the `dg[]` which returns the simplified derivative wrt `u` using `ruleg` to replace `g'[u]` with `f[u]` defined as the square root of the Weierstrass cubic.

NOTE: For those readers not familiar with the Weierstrass p-function $\wp(z)$, it satisfies the differential equation $\wp'(z)^2 = 4\wp^3 - g_2\wp(z) - g_3.$ Read the documentation for `InverseWeierstrassP` for some context. The question just renames $z,\wp,\wp',g_2,g_3$ into the cubic elliptic curve equation $$f(u)^2 = 4\ g(u)^3 -a\ g(u)- b. $$ Using this equation, we can express the first derivative of $\wp$ as $f(u)$ by taking the square root as in the definition `f[u_]`. We want to express higher derivatives of $f(u)$ also in terms of $g(u)$ using the equation relating $f(u)$ to $g(u)$. We can do this by **first** taking the derivative wrt $u$ of any expression involving $g(u)$, **and** then make the substitution of $f(u)$ in place of $g'(u)$. That is what the function `dg[]` does. Otherwise, Mathematica does not know that `g'[u] == f[u]` **unless** we use a rule to allow it to make the substitution whenever it finds `g'[u]`. There are other ways to get Mathematica to do the right thing, but I used a simple way to do it. An alternate way is this simple code

```
Derivative[1][g] ^= Function[u, Sqrt[4 g[u]^3 - a g[u] - b]];
f[u_] := g'[u] ; S = f'''[u]/f'[u] - 3/2 f''[u]^2/f'[u]^2 // Factor;
```

which uses `UpSet[]` to place a rule to evaluate `g'[]` in the `Derivative[]` function as in`UpValues`. This way is slicker, and does a specific thing which may be closer to what you wanted. My original method is more general.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why `f'[u]` does not work but defining it as `D[f0, u]` does?

Comment: @wanabephysicist Please read my lengthy NOTE.